# Dell XPS Laptop screen got dark

Tags: windows-8.1

I updated my windows 8 to 8.1 Pro, after that my screen got dark, now I can't make it bright, if you know any way to solve this problem please tell me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is older, and you can VERY faintly see that there is information on your screen, it is likely that the inverter has failed and needs replacement. It is not expensive.